# Alfresco - Not Able to Login after installation

Tags: alfresco, document-management

I installed Alfresco in my local Windows 7 machine, After successful installation I couldn't able to login  using the admin password which I gave while installing. I used the username as 'admin'

Im facing below error

`The remote server may be unavailable or your authentication details have not been recognized`

Please help me how to resolve this and proceed further

Comment: Which Alfresco version did you use? What is the output of your log?

Comment: Alfresco Community 4.2.

Comment: Are you trying to log into Share or the Alfresco Explorer (Repository)? If the former, try that latter, to ensure it actually started properly

Comment: I tried to login Share, Im getting 404 for http://localhost:8080/Alfresco. Is it problem with installation?

Comment: There is definalty issue with your alf installation. You need to check your logs you will find the issue.

Comment: try adding authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm,external1:external in alfresco-global.properties

Comment: be careful with activating external auth in your chain without ensuring that only your reverse proxy sets your Auth-header!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm,external1:external in alfresco-global.properties

Comment: Where we need to add this line? I mean which line?